# How do I get a task to execute of type Zip using 'dependsOn'?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to make my task `zipGui` execute on build target, but the only way I seem to be able to execute a task is if I remove the `(type: Zip)` from the task definition.

This snippet fails to execute the `zipGui` task at all:

```
task zipGui(type: Zip) {
  doFirst {
    println "==================== Zipping GUI components"
  }   

  doLast {
    FileTree zip = zipTree('assets/htdocs/gui.zip')
    from 'assets/htdocs'
  }   
}


build.dependsOn zipGui
```

And this executes the `zipGui` but it doesn't know anything about how to zip files:

```
task zipGui {
  doFirst {
    println "==================== Zipping GUI components"
  }   

  doLast {
    FileTree zip = zipTree('assets/htdocs/gui.zip')
    from 'assets/htdocs'
  }   
}


build.dependsOn zipGui
```

This is a stripped down fragment of the overall `build.gradle`.

How can I get `zipGui` to execute as a dependency of the build?

**EDIT**: here is more of the *real* `build.gradle` without me stripping things out to simplify the question:

```
  task copyCert(type: Copy) {
      from '../../../install'
      into 'assets/certs/root'
      include 'ca.pem'

      doFirst {
          println "==================== Copying root cert into assets"
      }
  }


  task copyGui(dependsOn: copyCert, type: Copy) {
      from '../../web/gui'
      into 'assets/htdocs'
      include '**/*.html'
      include '**/*.css'
      include '**/*.js'
      include '**/*.wav'
      include '**/*.tmpl'
      include '**/*.png'
      include '**/*.gif'
      include '**/*.jpg'
      exclude '**/*.DS_Store'
      exclude '**/.gitignore'
      exclude '**/.thumb'
      exclude '**/build'

      doFirst {
          println "==================== Copying gui components into assets"
      }
  }


  task zipGui(dependsOn: copyGui, type: Zip) {
      FileTree zip = zipTree('assets/htdocs/gui.zip')
      from 'assets/htdocs'

      doFirst {
          println "==================== Zipping GUI components"
      }
  }
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need to archive the files indicated in the copy tasks (copyGui, copyCert) into a zip named gui.zip. Am I right? It's an easy task here. you wrote it two complex. you can always merge the 3 tasks into one. 
By the way, zipTree is always used for unpacking packages.

Comment: @Nancy yep, you are right. That's exactly what I'm trying to do and I'm not surprised I made it too complex. I'll look at your answer and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check details of zip task here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html

```
      task zipGui(type: Zip) {
          archiveName = 'gui.zip'
          from("$projectDir/../../../install") {
              into 'assets/certs/root'
              include 'ca.pem'
          }
          from("$projectDir/../../web/gui"){
              into 'assets/htdocs'
              exclude '**/*.DS_Store'
              exclude '**/.gitignore'
              exclude '**/.thumb'
              exclude '**/build'
          }   // Just include or exclude is enough here as you indicated.
          destinationDir(file("$buildDir/libs"))
      }
```

Comment: Yay! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Your task simply has nothing to do.**

Gradle tasks are only executed, if they have something to do. If there is nothing to do (e.g. no files to zip), a task is skipped. There are multiple reasons for a task to have nothing to do. The main reason are up-to-date checks to prevent Gradle from doing the same thing what was done during the last invocation, at least as long as the task outputs are still available and the task inputs did not change.

However, in your specific case, the task has nothing to do, because at the time the task executes, no input files are specified at all. Files to include into the zip file can be added via `from`, which you do use. But, you use it inside a `doLast` closure, which is executed after the task actions (where the zipping takes place) were executed. Therefor, when running the zip process, the configuration did not take place.

You could use the regular configuration closure of the task or even the `doFirst` closure to configure your task:

```
task zipGui(type: Zip) {
    from 'assets/htdocs'
}

// OR

task zipGui(type: Zip) {
    doFirst {
        from 'assets/htdocs'
    }
}
```

Some more remarks:

- The line `FileTree zip = zipTree('assets/htdocs/gui.zip')` does absolutely nothing, because the created file tree is not queried. You need to either access the files of the file tree manually or pass it to a task, e.g. your zip task: `from zipTree('assets/htdocs/gui.zip')`
- In the second example, the task is executed because for normal tasks there are no automatic checks if there is any work to do, since a normal task can basically do everything the user makes it do.
- I'm not quite sure, but I think the second example should throw an exception, because a normal task without a type does not provide a `from` method.
- To get the status of each executed task and more insight generally, use the command line parameter `--console=plain`. The parameters `-d` and `--stacktrace` / `--full-stacktrace` may be used to get more information on errors.

Comment: Thank you for your well written answer. Unfortunately this still doesn't work. I might have pared too much from the `build.gradle` file so I've amended my question to include more of it. This shows tha    t `zipGui` depends on `copyGui` with further depends on `copyCert`. My goal is that by making the build depend on `zipGui` it will force `copyGui` to execute which will in turn force `copyCert` to exec    ute. The fact is, none of them are being triggered, yet the `zipGui` will trigger if I remove the `type: Zip` option. That baffles me

Comment: **You cannot configure a task in a `doLast` closure!** Every piece of configuration inside this closure won't be used.